# Why AVCaptureSession output a wrong orientation?

Tags: iphone, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

So, I followed Apple's instructions to capture video session using `AVCaptureSession`: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html. One problem I'm facing is that even though the orientation of the camera / iPhone device is vertical (and the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` shows a vertical camera stream), the output image seems to be in the landscape mode. I checked the width and height of imageBuffer inside `imageFromSampleBuffer:` of the sample code, and I got 640px and 480px respectively. Does anyone know why this's the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Take a look at the header AVCaptureSession.h. There is a definition for an enum called `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` that defines various video orientations. On the AVCaptureConnection object there is a property called videoOrientation that is a `AVCaptureVideoOrientation`. You should be able to set this to change the orientation of the video. You probably want `AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight` or `AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft`.

You can find the AVCaptureConnections for the session by looking at the outputs for the session. The outputs have a connections property that is an array of connections for that output.

Comment: `Property 'videoOrientation' not found on object of type 'AVCaptureSession *'`

Comment: @cheesus videoOrientation is on the AVCaptureConnection, not the AVCaptureSession

Comment: But where should i set this property in `AVCaptureConnection`? Inside the delegate method? something like: `- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];`

Comment: @rptwsthi you can set just after you add output into session `captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        let connection = videoOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVFoundation.AVMediaTypeVideo)
        connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
        captureSession.startRunning()`

Comment: I'd suggest doing the same after you change the camera lens, before committing the changes.

Comment: One thing I just realized is that AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight/Left has the opposite definition to UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight/Left. If UIDevice.current.orientation returns .landscapeLeft, set the AVCaptureVideo to .landscapeRight.

Answer (score 25):

Y'all are making this difficult.

In the DidOutputSampleBuffer, simply change the orientation before you grab the image. It's mono, but you have

```
    public class OutputRecorder : AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {    
        public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer (AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
        {
            try {
                connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
```

in objC it's this method

```
- ( void ) captureOutput: ( AVCaptureOutput * ) captureOutput
   didOutputSampleBuffer: ( CMSampleBufferRef ) sampleBuffer
      fromConnection: ( AVCaptureConnection * ) connection
```

Comment: just one thing I don't understand. When I use the camera with my ipad landscape I have to invert the videoOrientation. For example: if my ipad is `UIDeviceOrientationLeft` I have to do `connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight` and the same for the other landscape, or the image will be upside down. Why the video orientation has to be inverted in terms of device orientation is one more confuse thing thanks to Apple.

Comment: Works. Just remember to set the orientation asynchronously on the main queue, because this method is called on a special serial queue.

Comment: @SpaceDog If you look at the definitions of AVCaptureVideoOrientation and UIDeviceOrientation you'll see that the definitions of the landscape orientations are reversed in these enums. Why it's like this is beyond me, but it is documented. I agree it's confusing and assume there's some legacy reason they differ.

Comment: @SpaceDog It is because they are planes facing in opposite directions out of opposite sides of the phone. The left of the rear camera sensor is described as if you were looking at it from its front, i.e. the lens, but if your point of reference is the screen on the front of the device then it is reversed and this is on the right. For the front camera these are more intuitive because the sensor is in the same plane as the screen. It is confusing, but probably best to keep naming consistent in case phones don't always look the way they do today.

Answer (score 23):

I made a simple one-line modification to the `imageFromSampleBuffer` to correct the orientation problem (see my comment in the code under "I modified ...").  Hope it helps someone because I spent too much time on this.

```
// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer  {
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context1); 
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context1); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    //I modified this line: [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage]; to the following to correct the orientation:
    UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight]; 

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for me it helps. 
note the method taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924299/ios-capturing-image-using-avframework

Comment: @ReidBelton you cannot not be using AVCaptureConnection, its automatically created when you have an input and an output, you just gotta retrieve it and change the orientation.

Comment: I have an CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0 error

Answer (score 16):

Here is a right sequence:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoCaptureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoCaptureOutput]){
    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.videoCaptureOutput];
}else{
    NSLog(@"cantAddOutput");
}

// set portrait orientation
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [self.videoCaptureOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[conn setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
```

Comment: This worked for me. Like this code shows, it's important to add the output to the capture session before changing these properties. AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight with videoMirrored = true gave me the same effect that you get from using the standard camera app with front facing camera.

Comment: Doesn't this just change the orientation of the local `conn` object, rather than the one belonging to `self.videoCaptureOutput`?

Answer (score 13):

For instance:

```
AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection = <a capture connection>;
if ([captureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
    captureConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
}
```

The default appears to be `AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight`.

See also [QA1744: Setting the orientation of video with AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html).

Comment: this works for me, i added it to myAVCaptureConnection handler. It rotated the image as expected but the video is mirrored. I see that the isMirrored is deprecated so unclear how to fix the mirroring stuff b/c the new mirroring methods has no documentation on usage.

Comment: @Jim: Since `mirrored` in `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` has been deprecated, you should use `AVCaptureConnection`’s `videoMirrored` property instead. It is documented, at least in the header files, where `mirrored` and its friends also explicitly refers you to `videoMirrored` and the matching capture connection methods.

Answer (score 7):

For those people that need to work with CIImage and orientation from buffer is wrong I used this correction.

As easy as that. BTW the numbers 3,1,6,8 are from here https://developer.apple.com/reference/imageio/kcgimagepropertyorientation

And don't ask me why 3,1,6,8 is the right combination. I used brute-force method to find it. If you know why let the explanation in a comment please...

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    // common way to get CIImage

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer
                                                      options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];

    if (attachments) {
       CFRelease(attachments);
    }

    // fixing the orientation of the CIImage

    UIInterfaceOrientation curOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingOrientation:3];
    } else if (curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingOrientation:1];
    } else if (curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingOrientation:6];
    } else if (curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingOrientation:8];
    }



    // ....

}
```

Comment: The constants you are looking for are defined in kCGImagePropertyorientation... these come from the TIFF/EXIF spec:

https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/orientation.html

Answer (score 6):

If the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` orientation is correct, you can simply set the orientation before you capture the image.

```
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
NSData *capturedImageData;

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation];
}
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments =
            CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
    if (exifAttachments) {
        // Do something with the attachments.
    }
    // TODO need to manually add GPS data to the image captured
    capturedImageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:capturedImageData];
}];
```

Also, it's important to note that `UIImageOrientation` and `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` are different. `UIImageOrientationUp` refers to landscape mode with the volume controls *down* toward the ground (**not** up if you think about using the volume controls as a shutter button).

Thus, portrait orientation with the power button pointing to the sky (`AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait`) is actually `UIImageOrientationLeft`.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. You can also use:         connection.videoMirrored = true

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in the configuration of your video output, put these lines:

```
guard let connection = videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: 
AVFoundation.AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }
guard connection.isVideoOrientationSupported else { return }
guard connection.isVideoMirroringSupported else { return }
connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
connection.isVideoMirrored = position == .front
```

Then, configure your Target to support just Portait, by unchecking Landscape modes in General configuration.

([Source](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-camera-frames-extraction-d2c0f80ed05a))

Answer (score 2):

Orientation issue is with the front camera, so check device type and generate new image, it will definitely solve the orientation issue:

```
-(void)capture:(void(^)(UIImage *))handler{

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}

[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        **UIImage *capturedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if (self.captureDevice == [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][1]) {
            capturedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:capturedImage.CGImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
        }**

        handler(capturedImage);
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// #1
AVCaptureVideoOrientation newOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    // #2
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [captureSession connections]) {
        if ([connection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
            connection.videoOrientation = newOrientation;
            break;
        }
    } // #3
} else if ([previewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = newOrientation;
}
```

Once that you can correctly use your `AVCaptureSession`, you can set a video orientation.
Here a detailed description of the code above. Remember, this code has to be executed **after** the `[captureSession startRunning]` execution:

1. Choose the orientation that you prefer
2. For ios version >= 13.0 you have to retrieve the active connection from the `captureSession`. Remember: only video connection supports `videoOrientation`
3. For ios version < 13.0 you can use the connection from the `previewLayer`

If your viewController doesn't have a fixed orientation you can set a new `videoOrientation` to your connection once the device orientation changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
private func startLiveVideo() {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

    let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
    let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    captureSession.addInput(input)
    captureSession.addOutput(output)

    output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    output.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait

    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work? Because when I "just try this", it doesn't

Comment: Did you call the private startLiveVideo() func? What the problem did you get?