# iOS AVCaptureSession - How to get/set the number of frames per second recorded?

Tags: ios, frame-rate, avcapturesession

I'm new to AVCaptureSession and wish to better understand how to work with it.
So I managed capturing the video stream as separated CIImages and convert them to UIImages.
Now I wish to be able to get the number of Frames Per Second captured and preferably to be able to set it.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `AVCaptureConnection`'s `videoMinFrameDuration` accessor to set the value.

See the [AVCaptureConnection documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Consider `output` be `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` object.

```
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (conn.isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported)
    conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
if (conn.isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported)
    conn.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
```

More info, see my answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924299/ios-capturing-image-using-avframework/8924411#8924411)

Comment: Is my fps guaranteed to not drop below my min/max values? How I can get my current actual fps, rather than the min and max?

Comment: @TylerPfaff did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @Crashalot it's been too long, I don't remember :(

Comment: These properties are now deprecated. Is there any alternate method?

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu check my answer below. I have updated it.

Comment: Also note that setting `activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` must be done _after_ adding it to your session. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34720352/1271826.

Answer (score 22):

`AVCaptureConnection's videoMinFrameDuration` is deprecated.

You can use `AVCaptureDevice` properties to detect supported video frame rate ranges and can assign minimum and maximum frame rates using properties.

`device.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges` return all video frame rates ranges supported by device.

`device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` can be used for specifying frame durations.

Answer (score 14):

To set the capture session frame rate, you have to set it on the device using **device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration** and **device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration** (if necessary).

In **Swift 4** you can do something like this:

```
extension AVCaptureDevice {
    func set(frameRate: Double) {
    guard let range = activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.first,
        range.minFrameRate...range.maxFrameRate ~= frameRate
        else {
            print("Requested FPS is not supported by the device's activeFormat !")
            return
    }

    do { try lockForConfiguration()
        activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(frameRate))
        activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(frameRate))
        unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("LockForConfiguration failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

And call it

```
device.set(frameRate: 60)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this

```
if let frameSupportRange = currentCamera.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.first {
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    // currentCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, Int32(frameSupportRange.maxFrameRate))
    currentCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, YOUR_FPS_RATE)
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}
```