# Is there a function to get 10 frames per second of video?

Tags: ios, swift, frame, cmtime, avassetimagegenerator

I am trying to get 10 frames per second of video from `imagePickerController`. I use this function, but images from 0.1s -> 1s are the same, from 1.1 to 2s too. Is there anyway to do? This is my function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL
        getAllFrames(videoURL)
    }
```

```
var frames:[UIImage] = []
private var generator:AVAssetImageGenerator!
func getAllFrames(_ videoUrl: URL) {
        let asset:AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
        let duration:Double = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
        self.generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset:asset)
        self.generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        var i: Double = 0
        repeat {
            self.getFrame(fromTime: i)
            i = i + 0.1
        } while (i < duration)
        self.generator = nil
    }
```

```
private func getFrame(fromTime:Double) {
        let time:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, preferredTimescale: 600)
        let image:CGImage
        do {
            try image = self.generator.copyCGImage(at:time, actualTime:nil)
        } catch {
            return
        }
        self.frames.append(UIImage(cgImage:image))
    }
```

Or do I need to increase video quality? Thanks for help.

Comment: What framerate is your input video?

Comment: I added this line `imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeHigh` and everything work fine. But I still don't how many frame is it?

Comment: Instead of making the image picker controller do the work of rewriting the video, why don't you return to the original PHAsset and get its video data directly?

Comment: I still don't have knowledge about PHAsset. In my case, I want to get 10 frames per second from camera. I tried to record video and get frames from that video. May be it isn't a good solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: So you are using the image picker controller to function as the camera? You didn't say that in your question. Again, a better option would be to use AVFoundation where you have more control over what the camera does. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039251/ios-avcapturesession-how-to-get-set-the-number-of-frames-per-second-recorded