# Calling C functions from Objective-C - Passing large amounts of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, video

I have an iOS app that processes video frames from captureOutput straight from the camera. As part of the processing I'm calling several C functions in another source file. I convert UIImages into raw data and pass these rapidly - all of the processing is done on a queue tied to the video output.

This seems to work fine, up to a point. It seems that I'm hitting a limit when the data I'm passing becomes too large and I get seemingly random EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors popping up during the initialisation phase of the C function.
By initialisation I mean, declaring small static arrays and setting them to zero and suchlike.

I was wondering if I was hitting some kind of stack limit with passing large amounts of data so tried upping the stack size using Other Linker Flags and the -Wl,-stack_size,  but this didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there anything else I should be aware of calling C functions from a non-UI thread in this way?

Sorry to be a little general, but I'm unable to post specifics of the code and am looking for general advice and tips for this kind of situation.

Some further information - we had issues with releasing memory and used autorelease pools in the video processing side in Objective-C (as recommended as we're on a different thread) - perhaps we're hitting the same difficulty with the C code. Is there a way to increase the frequency that releases/frees are executed in C or am I just chasing my tail?

Comment: I would suggest to edit the title of your post/question so that it reflects an problem when passing large input to C functions from Objective C. Other than that, I have nothing to suggest, sorry :(

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem with the nature of C/Objective-C it sounds like you have bad memory access somewhere

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to track down any memory issues and the app is stable in memory (real and virtual) according to Instruments and receives no memory warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including several @autoreleasepool blocks around some key areas of code, we identified the major cause of the memory problems we were having.

It seemed that including the following block just inside the captureOutput callback function did the trick.

```
@autoreleaspool
  {
  imageColour = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
  }
```

Note: imageFromSampleBuffer was taken from this question
[ios capturing image using AVFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924299/ios-capturing-image-using-avframework)

Answer (score 0):

So, the root of your problem is memory usage. Even if you don't leak any memory and are very careful, writing an video processing app on iOS is very tricky because there is only so much memory you can actually allocate in the app before the OS will terminate your app due to memory use. If you would like to read my blog post about the this subject, you can find it at [video_and_memory_usage_on_ios](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post5_video_and_memory_usage_on_ios_devices/index.html). Some easy rules to remember are that you basically can allocate and use something like 10 megs of memory for a short time, but anything more than that and you risk upsetting the os and your app can be terminated. With virtual mapped memory in a file, the upper limit is a total of about 700 megs for all mapped memory at any one time. This is not a stack issue, I am talking about heap memory. You should not be putting video memory on the stack, that is just crazy. Be careful to only pass around pointers to memory and NEVER copy the memory from one buffer into another, just pass around refs to the memory in the buffer. The iOS APIs in CoreGraphics and CoreVideo support this type of "allocate a buffer and pass around the pointer" type of approach. The other rule of thumb to remember is to only process one frame at a time and then reuse the same buffer to process the next frame after the data has been written to a file or into a h.264 video via the AVAssets APIs.