# Fix orientation for custom camera app iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera

Based on the custom camera tutorial: https://github.com/brianadvent/CustomCamera

On trying to build from it. Observed that camera didn't rotated as expected. App worked perfectly in portrait mode, however in landscape mode it worked in unexpected mode. In landscape mode, the camera view didnt pan out as the default camera does.

Looked into previous post like: [cannot change AVCaptureVideoDataOutput orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745771/cannot-change-avcapturevideodataoutput-orientation)

But these outdated posts. Hence had to repost it again.

Screenshot in portrait mode:
[image]

Screenshot in landscape mode:
[image]

Following is the code for `ViewController.swift`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer:CALayer!
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!
    var takePhoto = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        prepareCamera()
    }

    func prepareCamera() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices.first {
            captureDevice = availableDevices
            beginSession()
        }
    } // prepareCamera

    func beginSession () {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]
        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()


        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.brianadvent.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        takePhoto = true

    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if takePhoto {
            takePhoto = false

            if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {

                let photoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! PhotoViewController
                photoVC.takenPhoto = image
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: { 
                        self.stopCaptureSession()
                    })
                } // dispatch
            } // if image
        } //takePhoto
    } // captureOutput


    func getImageFromSampleBuffer (buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            let context = CIContext()

            let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

            if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .right)
            }
        } // if pixelBuffer

        return nil
    } // getImageFromSampleBuffer

    func stopCaptureSession () {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }

    } // stopCaptureSession


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } // didReceiveMemoryWarning


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Check AVCaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported or not

Step 2: If yes, set VideoOrientation of AVCaptureConnection portrait or landscapeRight.

Replace with this function your issue will be solved.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if takePhoto {
        takePhoto = false
        if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
            connection.videoOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait ? .portrait : .landscapeRight
        }
        if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {

            let photoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! PhotoViewController

            photoVC.takenPhoto = image

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.stopCaptureSession()
                })

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed orientation with

```
detectionOverlay.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 0.5)).scaledBy(x: scale, y: -scale))
```

and

```
captureConnection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
```

here's a demo I use landscapeRight to detect object.