# Lock orientation in iOS app dynamically with Swift (AVCaptureSession)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, orientation, avcapturesession

Is there a way to lock the orientation on event / tap? I am using an AVCaptureSession to record videos but I would like to lock the orientation for the App once the record started.

Comment: You can find your answer in stake overflow.
[Why AVCaptureSession output a wrong orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561738/why-avcapturesession-output-a-wrong-orientation)

Comment: I have already set up the videoOrientation property – what I am searching for is a way to lock the orientation on event – not defining the right orientation in my capture outputs (I have already done that).