# Capture camera image along with live filters Using AVFoundation in IOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4

I am making Live Sticker app and capturing image using AVFoundation.
The issue i am getting is that when i save image it save only image not stickers that are placed on image 
I have 2 issues
1=> Save image with live stickers 
2=> Change image orientation to portrait mode

Camera preview layer  code [**I am getting just image not live sticker**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbesF.jpg)

[**I want to save image with sticker like shown in image but getting only image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNce0.jpg)

```
     func setupCameraPreview() {
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    let rootLayer = self.overlay.layer

    rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
    self.previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
}
```

I am saving image using this code

```
    private func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    let context = CIContext()
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw image along with overlay stickers.

Suppose You have `preview`  view in which you added the sticker.
`image` is image you got from `imageFromSampleBuffer` or `stillImage`

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = preview.bounds
//   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
preview.addSubview(imageView)
preview.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
var layer: CALayer? = preview.layer
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((layer?.frame.size)!, false, 0.0)
if let aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    layer?.render(in: aContext)
}
var img: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

 self.yourImageView.image = img
```

Comment: Getting from imageFromSampleBuffer

Comment: 1st issue resolve but image orientation is still in landscape mode & sticker is in portrait mode when i rotate device to landscape i give potraite mode

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561738/why-avcapturesession-output-a-wrong-orientation

Comment: How to record video with same scenario?